# how to print out UInt16 pointer to NSLog

Tags: iphone, ios, nslog

I am just trying to print out UInt16 pointer to my log, So i can see its contence... however thus far am not having any sucsess, dose anyone know how to do this, I am thinking its the format specifier but because I dont have alot of experience with this type of thing I just dont know. the warning I am getting is **"initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type"**

```
//....
    [nissanCode seekToFileOffset: 2];
    dataBuffer = [nissanCode readDataOfLength:SETSIZE];
    UInt16 *ans = dataBuffer.bytes;
    UInt16 a = *ans;
    NSLog (@"Data = %@", a);
//....
```

//Revised code that clears the warning and prints data out fine. thanks for the help guys.

```
//....
    [nissanCode seekToFileOffset: 2];
    dataBuffer = [nissanCode readDataOfLength:SETSIZE];
    const UInt16 *ans = dataBuffer.bytes; 
    NSLog (@"Data = %d", a);
//....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using for int's

```
NSLog(@"Data = %d", a);
```

or for your UInt16's (thanks to @bshirley for the list of format specifiers below)

```
NSLog(@"Data = %hu", a);
```

Comment: here is a list of the [string format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265) which can be used in `stringWithFormat:` and `NSLog` and many others

Comment: thanks @bshirley, I went looking for that list but couldn't find it. that should fix up his warnings.

Comment: @aran i always find it by looking up [NSString stringWithFormat:] doc, which has a link to it

Comment: @bshirley good way to get there, I put a link to it from my blog as well, handy link to have around. I would actually do this NSLog statement with a stringWithFormat: rather than how it is done above.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print the address or the value? From how your code is setup you should be using `%d`, but for the pointer you would use `NSLog("%p", ans);`. The `%@` format is for objects only.